# Snap ins, Pre chat form - adding custom fields

Tags: servicecloud, pre-chat

I'm trying to figure out how to add a custom field from Case Object to the pre-chat form. I saw a video from salesforce and I see it was possible.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdnxS8MYSr0 
Time: 38:26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes It's possible...but if custom field is text-area...long text area..rich text area...will not supported in pre-chat here....

Comment: Thanks, this works! Do you know if there is any way to allow long text in the pre-chat form?